# Using php Session Variables To Fetch Data From MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, variables

I'm trying to use php session variables in a SELECT Statement to fetch the data stored in a multiple array database. 
However, I am facing some challenges with my code below:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['array'])) {
    if($_SESSION['array'] == 'arrayname') {

        $query = "SELECT '{$_SESSION['option']}' FROM '{$_SESSION['array']}' WHERE '{$_SESSION['key']}'='".mysqli_real_escape_string( $link, '{$_SESSION['value']}')."'";

        if ($result=mysqli_query( $link, $query)) {

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo $row['{$_SESSION['value']}'];

            }

        }
        mysqli_close($link); // Closing Connection with Server
    }
} ?>
```

Any attempt to fetch the data with the above code rather displays an error messages, like;

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'value' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\content\fetchData.php on line 5
```

I will be much grateful for a way out to deal with this challenge. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too many errors and too many unknowns.

Comment: Just a tip, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches in the future if you assign values in `$_SESSION, $_POST, $_GET`, etc. to a variable before using it. IE: `$option = $_SESSION['option']`, then `SELECT '{$option}'`.  Also, if these values are user input you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when you store them in `$_SESSION`, that way you don't have to call the function every time you use the value it will already be clean. Lastly, when all else fails you can always call `die($query);` right after you define `$query` Then you can check your query for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query, get your variable first:

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link, $_SESSION['value']);
```

Then use `$value` rather than try and embed like you have above.

You don't need the single quotes or the curly braces around `$_SESSION` when you are echoing the value. Just do this:

```
echo $row[$_SESSION['value']];
```

That should fix your current error, however you still have more issues with your code. Namely you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions, which won't work. Move your code over to `mysqli` completely.